# Django URLconf: How to use captured params in include's RedirectView?

Tags: python, django, redirect, url-pattern, urlconf

I have a parent URLconf:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^main/(?P<name>[^/]+)/(?P<region>[^/]+)/(?P<id>[^/]+)/', include('foo')),
)
```

And a child URLconf (included in the parent) that includes a redirect:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^view/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/main/%(name)s/%(region)s/%(id)s/detail')),
)
```

(Essentially, I'm trying to redirect a path that looks like `/main/product/1/134/view` to a path that looks like `/main/product/1/134/detail`.)

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters) says that "An included URLconf receives any captured parameters from parent URLconfs."

But when I try access `/main/product/1/134/view`, I get a `KeyError` because `name` isn't recognized.

Is there some other way that I have to reference the received captured parameters in the RedirectView?

Note: I don't get an error when I do the whole thing in the parent URLconf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^main/(?P<name>[^/]+)/(?P<region>[^/]+)/(?P<id>[^/]+)/view/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/main/%(name)s/%(region)s/%(id)s/detail'))
)
```

Comment: you could refer the captured groups by referring the group index number `\1` or name.

Answer (score 4):

[This section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) suggests that you should be using two percent signs instead of one:

> The given URL may contain dictionary-style string formatting, which will be interpolated against the parameters captured in the URL. Because keyword interpolation is always done (even if no arguments are passed in), any "%" characters in the URL must be written as "%%" so that Python will convert them to a single percent sign on output.

So in your case, try:

```
url(r'^view/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/main/%%(name)s/%%(region)s/%%(id)s/detail')),
```

It might be cleaner to use the [`pattern_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.pattern_name) argument instead of `url`. The `args` and `kwargs` will be used to reverse the new url.

```
url(r'^view/$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='name_of_url_pattern_to_redirect_to')),
```

Comment: When I use "%%" it resolves to "%" in output, but doesn't perform any string substitution, so the URL it redirects to is `'/main/%(name)s/%(region)s/%(id)s/detail` (which of course is invalid).